# How to disprove : If $a\mid c, b \mid d$, then $(a + b)\mid (c + d)$

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory

It is given that for non-zero integers $a,b,c,d$, if $a \mid c$ and $b \mid d$, then prove or disprove $(a+b) \mid (b+c)$.

Let $c = ae$, for a non-zero integer $e$; and $d = bf$, for a non-zero integer $f$.

There is no way for me to prove or even disprove, except by taking a failure case. Like, $a = 2, b = 3, c = 4, d =9, e =1, f=1$; and hence fails as $5\nmid 13$.

If any property of (say) linear combinations is useful here, then please help.

*Addendum* May be, linear algebra is applicable here.

Comment: you need only one failure case to disprove something

Comment: But, a theoretical answer is what makes the proof theoretically good too. Any sort of technique, if applicable...

Comment: If this was valid then you can think about a proof. The equation you suggest seems blatantly false, then why do you need a theoretical construct

Comment: If it isn't true, then it isn't true. There doesn't have to be some profound reasoning or theoretical proof behind it. Had it _been_ true, on the other hand, then a proof would (probably) give insight into the mechanisms behind why it is so.

Comment: No, a "theoretical" answer makes no sense when the statement is false and just needs a counter example.

Comment: So, I will take the last three comments as basis for disproving by just a counter-example, and with no need for theoretical basis.

Comment: http://www.openculture.com/2015/04/shortest-known-paper-in-a-serious-math-journal.html Math papers have been published using an example to disprove something. Just to emphasize there is nothing wrong in using an example to disprove something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit long for a comment: Given some arbitrarily constructed property of numbers (or anything else, really), the general attitude to have is that the property is some times true, and some times not. If you have to prove this, then one example of each is enough.

On the other hand, where it gets interesting, and needs theoretical proofs and reasons, is on one of the following cases:

1. it is always true
2. it is never true
3. the cases where it is true and the cases where it is false are easily classifiable / corresponds to where some other, seemingly unrelated (or, at least, not immediately equivalent) property is true and false

You were not asked to do any of these three, and thus an example is enough.

Comment: If it were, and one must argue (without that knowledge, beforehand) that there is basis in property that : - sum of two different vectors not always dividing their linear combination. Here, a,b are two vectors, and ae + bf is their linear combination. I hope there is basis to this property. I hope, it should be provable easily by linear agebra.

Comment: Seemingly, vector division is not easily portable to be used in elementary number theory; and hence our simple cases need no further proof than a failure case.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done far more simply: $a=b =1$, $c=2,d=3$.

$1|2, 1|3$, but $1+1$ does NOT divide $2+3$.

If you require $a,b,c,d$ distinct then $a=1,b=3,c=2,d=9$ will work just as well.

ETA: As you noted already OP.